# Can you identify this pattern?

Tags: pattern, knowledge

> North, North, South, South, West, East, West, East, First, Second

Can anyone identify this famous pattern?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution:

> Is the Konami code

Because:

> **up up down down left right left right 1 2**
>
>  Is a cheat code to give the player a full set of power-ups
>
> The original version of the cheat code was designed for the NES controller. The exact sequence varies from game to game and has been adapted to fit the button layouts of different video game consoles

Comment: Wow, That was fast. I'd expected it to last longer. Oh well, good job. I'll accept it when I can.

Comment: ^^' i didnt know about the konami code. i thought it was like GTA cheat code

Comment: Well you learn something new everyday!

Comment: sure i do ! more with the SE network !

Comment: That's news to me... I never knew about this cheat...